# C# 非同期処理でどのやり方を使えばいいのか知りたい。

Tags: c#

参考書のにタスク、スレッドプール、パラレルと　async,awaitの４っの同じようなやり方？
のやり方が記載されているのですがつまりどれを使えばいいのでしょうか？

```
class Program  
{           

    public static async Task<int> method()
    {
        return await Task<int>.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("finish");
            return 1;
        });
    }

    public static void method2(Object t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finish");
    }

    public static void method3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finish");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ThreadPool  
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(method2),"1");
        //task
        Task task = Task.Run(new Action(method3));
        //Parallel
        Parallel.Invoke(new Action(method3));

        Task<int> t = method();
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: 実行したい処理の性質によるのでは？それを知らない誰かが断言できるものでは無いでしょう。この辺の記事を参考にしてみてください。[非同期処理の種類](https://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/AsyncVariation.html), [【C#】TPL：Parallelによる並列処理](http://kageura.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2015/04/10/190000), [C#ざっくりマルチスレッド(非同期処理)](http://gomocool.net/gomokulog/?p=762)

Comment: 質問なのですが、どれも用途が違うので使えるようにしておくべきなのでしょうか？C#のバージョンがどうとか書いたあるので

Comment: 必要になった時に、詳細を調査・検討出来るくらいには、概要を把握しておいた方が良いとは思います。まあ能力と時間は有限なので、理想と現実の兼ね合いですね。どの程度を良しとするかは人それぞれでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば、
「画面のダウンロードボタンを押した後に画面を固まった状態にしたくない」といった単純な用途なら、async/awaitが良いでしょう。
これはTaskの糖衣構文です（7.0以降はもう少し抽象化してTaskに依存しなくなってますが…）。

ただし、ちゃんと使いこなそうとしたらTaskの概念、
コンソールプログラムとWindows ControlやWPFなどUIパーツ利用プログラムの挙動の違い、
UIパーツをnewする際の制限事項など覚える必要があります。

Comment: つまりどれも使うということなのでしょうか？

Comment: 概要を知るなら、こちらを参照してください。https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/masterasync_01/masterasync_01_01.html